# Drill through facts attributs

Tags: ssas, hierarchy, bigdata, cube, drillthrough

I am working on a big cube, I am using a drill through action to get the details of my products, so the details have to be dimension attributs to be able to display them.

I wish to display other field that are part of the fact table (Product reference), How can I do that ?

thank you in advance.

note : I used drill through because I want to avoid to put product in the grain level of my product hierarchy, when I do that I get big performance issus.

Comment: What version of SSAS are you using? If 2012, is it tabular of multidimensional?  I'm assuming  multidimensional.  Are you saying that you have a field in a fact table in your DSV that you didn't include as a dimension or measure and you would like to include it in drillthrough?  Or is this field available somewhere in the cube?

Comment: I have SSAS 2008 and I am using multidimensional databases.Yes, that is exactly what I want to do, the field is available only in the DSV.   @mmarie

Comment: I suppose that you could make that field a property of a dimension rather than an actual dimension attribute and then write your own drillthrough action rather than use the UI so you can include it in the query.  Here's a good link for that. http://www.solidq.com/sqj/Pages/Business_Intelligence/SSAS-Cube-Exploration-Digging-Through-the-Details-with-Drillthrough.aspx  Otherwise, I think you have to include the field as a dimension member.

Comment: Similar question on MSDN supports my thought http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/773b3d5e-892f-40ff-a975-3b54a381fe21/how-do-you-include-non-aggregate-data-into-excell-drilldown-results

Comment: from the two links I concluded that I have to have the attributs in the dimension to be able to perform a drill through action.I think I will do that and I will hide the details' attributs and put them in a drill through action. thank you for all @mmarie